# Omniauth with pow port issue in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, port, omniauth, rack-pow

I'm using Omniauth in my Rails app (which is launched locally using POW). After my providers return to the callback action, I get redirect back in port 19999. I don't want to hard code the port into the redirect_to (e.g.: `redirect_to root_url, :port => PORT`).

I want either to get the port dynamically or understand why the port is 19999.

If I launch my app normally (`rails s -p 3000`), the port doesn't change to 19999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup callback url's host with `OmniAuth.config.full_host` like:

```
OmniAuth.config.full_host = "http://yourapp.dev"
```

This must be placed before omniauth is called. I think `config/initializes/omniauth.rb` is good.